# Segmentation fault loading dictionary. Is it being caused by calloc, sys/stat.h or something else?

Tags: c, dictionary, dynamic-arrays, trie, calloc

This function is supposed to load a dictionary into a trie. I wanted to find out how large the dictionary file was so I could `calloc` all the memory at once. The reason for this being so that all the memory would be located close together and could therefor take advantage of hardware that helps speed up the search. Too do this I found recommendations for 2 methods. One of them is the use of `sys/stat.h` that you will see in my code.

When I run this code I receive a "segmentation fault" which I know means I am trying to access memory I don't have permission for. Through the use of GDB I have found that the segmentation fault occurs on line 116( a.k.a: the line that reads "else if (cur->children[key] == NULL)") I have found that the value in key at that time is 12. At first I thought that the problem was my use of `calloc` or `sys/stat.h` since these are the 2 things that I know the least about that I made use of. However the more I research them the less likely this seems. If it is not one of these then I don't even have a clue where to look anymore.

Bellow is only the code I believe to be relevant:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

typedef struct node
{
    bool end[26]; 

    struct node* children[26]; 
} node;

node* start;

int key;
int last;
int dic_count;

bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    struct stat s;
    stat(dictionary, &s);
    int size = s.st_size;

    dic_count = 0;

    int z = 1;

    FILE* dic = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dic == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    start = calloc(size, sizeof(node));

    if (start == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int l = 0;
    int d;

    node* cur = &start[0];

    while (0 != (d = fgetc(dic)))
    {
        int d = fgetc(dic);

        if (l > 0)
        {
            last = key;
        }

        l = 1;

        key = d - 'a';

        if (d == '\n')
        {
            cur->end[last] = true;
            cur = &start[0];
            dic_count++;
        }
        else if (cur->children[key] == NULL)
        {
            node* new = &start[z];

            cur->children[key] = new;

            z++;

            if (cur->children[key] == NULL)
            {
                return false;
            }

            cur = cur->children[key];
        }
        else
        {
            cur = cur->children[key];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `start` pointing to *throughout* all this code? **one dynamic node** ? I think you're going to need more than that.

Comment: start points at the first dynamic node in the calloced memory. The other nodes are created in that memory. start is just the starting point not the entire storage.

Comment: I'm not sure that the file size is a good estimate for the number of nodes you'll need. When you read, you distinguis newline from other characters, which you assume to be lower-case letters. That seems error prone to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your file contains a binary 0? If you trying to read till the end of file, test `fgetc` result against EOF, not 0. Otherwise your loop never terminates.

Besides that, you only processing every second character.

**Expanding as requested**:

From `man fgetc`:

> fgetc(), getc() and getchar() return the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error

You are probably confusing it with `fgets` return value.

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
```

is safe and sound. Again, the source of possible confusion is unsoundness of

```
while (!feof(fp))
```

Now, regarding unprocessed characters: you wrote

```
    while (0 != (d = fgetc(dic)))
    {
        int d = fgetc(dic);
```

The code reads a character in `while` expression, compares it to 0, and reads a (next) character. A first character is lost.

Comment: fgetc will return 0 when there is nothing for it to return. I have read that is not good to use EOF because the way it is made it runs through 1 extra time after it hits the end of the file so you end up with junk values. As to the only processing every second character could you explain more fully ?

Comment: @stjwiv: What you've heard is that you shouldn't use extra tests with `feof` in your code. `EOF` is a special integer constant that indicates the end of file (or reading error) in some `<stdio.h>` functions. (If the file you read were a binary file, there might well be a zero in it, so `fgetc` returns the char value in the range 0-255 or the special constant `EOF`, which is usually -1.)

Comment: @user58697: You are right this fixed the problem. The crazy part is that I noticed this when I was making changes before and I had intended to fix it. That is why  int  d  is defined both before and after the while loop. I guess I never finished fixing it. Thanks for the help.